# Ubuntu 12.04 Touchpad Menu Gone

Tags: 12.04, mouse, touchpad

I just got a new laptop (Asus g46) and have had several issues with it, odd since I've never had issue with Ubuntu and I've used it since 7.04.

Anyway, my touchpad menu is gone in the Mouse and Touchpad menu, which is rather annoying because I'd like to have it disable while type so my palms don't click elsewhere, as well as re-enable scrolling since I can't do that anymore as well.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to disable the touchpad while tapping text is to add the following command in the startup utility, as a new entry, named as you wish:

syndaemon -k -i 2 -d &

Reboot and you should be able to type text with no more touchpad messing around with your palms.

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm! Now, do you have any solution for edge or two finger scrolling? If I can get that fixed, I'm set! Thanks!

Comment: Try to install GPointing from the Ubuntu Software Center. It's a Gnome utility to tweak the mouse and touchpad settings, more accurate than the ubuntu utility in Settings.

Comment: Thanks but the issue is it won't recognize it as a touchpad, even GPointing sees it as a ps/2 generic mouse.

Comment: FYI, I had to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04, working with Unity alone (I haven't installed any extra Gnome-related stuff) and the touchpad is nicely managed with System > Mouse and Touchpad. I guess you can quickly mess things up if you install other touchpad utilities, even if the Syndaemon tool keep working.